# How to resolve XML5686: Unspecified XML error in IE console

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I am working on primefaces application

where I have a data table and column headers as input field, I can filter the table values by column headers.

Everything is working fine when there is about 20 to 50 rows in a particular column, but when there are more than 50 rows in any column the datatable is not getting updated after ajax call.

The problem is coming only in IE, and in the console the below error is coming
**XML5686: Unspecified XML error line number:xx, column number XX**

While googling I found that, it's problem with IE when there is large data.

Have used following below code to resolve:

```
 <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </f:facet>
```

But, still no luck.

Envorinment:

1. Primefaces 5.x,
2. IE 11

Hers is my xhtml code:

```
  <p:dataTable id="myGrid" widgetVar="myGrid" value="#{myBean.lazyDataModel}" lazy="true" var="p" rowKey="#{p.id}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.currentPst}"
                emptyMessage="#{msgs.no_records_found}" draggableColumns="true"  liveResize="true"
                filterDelay="600" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} #{msgs.of} {totalPages})" styleClass="pst-grid" rowStyleClass="#{p.leadPst ?  'test' : ''}">

                <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{myBean.onDataTablePageChange}"/>

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onPstSelect}" global="false"/>

                <p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{myBean.onColumnReorder}"/>

                <p:ajax event="sort" listener="#{myBean.onColumnSort}"/>



                <p:column headerText="${msgs.test}" id="materialsColumn" field="materials" exportable="true"
                    filterBy="" filterStyleClass="hidefilter" sortBy="#{pst.materials}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-column-title-block" value="${msgs.pst_materials}" />
                    </f:facet>                      
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:inputMask value="#{myBean.filter.mt}" styleClass="ui-column-inputfield"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ui:repeat var="mat" value="#{p.mts}" exportSeparator="\r\n">                                   
                        <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{labelBean.formatMaterialNumber(mat.mt.mnum)}" /><br/>
                        <p:tooltip for="outputText">
                            <ui:repeat var="mater" value="#{p.mts}" exportSeparator="\r\n">                                 
                                <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{mater.md.label}" /><br/>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </p:tooltip>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:column>


                /// othre columns
            </p:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: There is some kind of a limit to XML size in IE11. AFAIK there is no fix. Instead think about showing less rows + pagination, or offer exporting a report instead.